# Apache Flink join different DataStreams on specific key

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, data-stream

I have two `DataStreams`, the first one called `DataStream<String> source` which receive records from a message broker, and the second one is a `SingleOutputOperator<Event> events`, which is the result of mapping the source into `Event.class`.

I have a uses cases that needs to use `SingleOutputOperator<Event> events` and other that uses `DataStream<String> source`. In one of the use cases that use `DataStream<String> source`, I need to join the `SingleOutputOperator<String> result` after apply some filters and to avoid to map the `source` again into `Event.class` as I already have that operation done and that `Stream`, I need to search each record into the `SingleOutputOperator<String> result` into the `SingleOutputOperator<Event> events` and the apply another map to export a  `SingleOutputOperator<EventOutDto> out`.

This is the idea as example:

```
DataStream<String> source = env.readFrom(source);
SingleOutputOperator<Event> events = source.map(s -> mapper.readValue(s, Event.class));


public void filterAndJoin(DataStream<String> source, SingleOutputOperator<Event> events){
  
  SingleOutputOperator<String> filtered = source.filter(s -> new FilterFunction());
  
  SingleOutputOperator<EventOutDto> result = (this will be the result of search each record 
      based on id in the filtered stream into the events stream where the id must match and return the event if found)
.map(event -> new EventOutDto(event)).addSink(new RichSinkFunction());
}
```

I have this code:

```
filtered.join(events)
                    .where(k -> {
                        JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(k);
                        String id = "";
                        if (tree.get("Id") != null) {
                            id = tree.get("Id").asText();
                        }
                        return id;
                    })
                    .equalTo(e -> {
                        return e.Id;
                    })
                    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
                    .apply(new JoinFunction<String, Event, BehSingleEventTriggerDTO>() {
                        @Override
                        public EventOutDto join(String s, Event event) throws Exception {
                            return new EventOutDto(event);
                        }
                    })
                    .addSink(new SinkFunction());
```

In the above code all works fine, the `ids` are the same, so basically the `where(id).equalTo(id)` should work, but the process never reaches the `apply` function.

Observation: `Watermark` are assigned with the same timestamp

Questions:

- Any idea why?
- Am I explained myself fine?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the join by doing this:

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<ObjectDTO> triggers = candidates
                    .keyBy(new KeySelector())
                    .intervalJoin(keyedStream.keyBy(e -> e.Id))
                    .between(Time.milliseconds(-2), Time.milliseconds(1))
                    .process(new new ProcessFunctionOne())
                    .keyBy(k -> k.otherId)
                    .process(new ProcessFunctionTwo());
```